# how to create a list of elements from an XML file in python

Tags: python, xml

my XML

```
<root>
- <Book category="Children">
  <title>Harry Potter</title> 
  <author>J.K</author> 
  <year>2005</year> 
  <price>29.99</price> 
  </Book>
- <Book category="WEB">
  <title>Learning XML</title> 
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author> 
  <year>2003</year> 
  <price>39.95</price> 
  </Book>
</root>
```

I'm using etree in python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
Books = ET.parse('4.xml') #parse the xml file into an elementtre
```

were the list of elements i would like to receive is

BookInfo = [title,author,year,price]

2) how would it be corect to read the Text  in a specific elemnt of the list BookInfo

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    Books = ET.parse('4.xml') #parse the xml file into an elementtre
    root = Books.getroot()
    for child in root:
        BookInfo = [
        child.find('title').text,
        child.find('author').text,
        child.find('year').text,
        child.find('price').text
        ]
        print (BookInfo)
```

2)if you can receive the specific element from the list use BookInfo[0] - this is title, BookInfo[1] - author...